# How to implement sklearn's tf-idf as script score in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I try to implement sklearn TfidfVectorizer's way of calculating the tf-idf in elasticsearch, so that i can compare both results.

[sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#:%7E:text=The%20formula%20that%20is%20used,document%20frequency%20of%20t%3B%20the) computes the tf-idf (by default) like this:

```
tf-idf(t, d) = tf(t, d) * idf(t)
```

with:

```
idf(t) = log [ (1 + n) / (1 + df(t)) ] + 1
```

and tf(t, d) simply being the raw term frequency without scaling/weighting

[elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/index-modules-similarity.html) (with lucene under the hood) which by default implements BM25, which is based on tf-idf, suggests to implement basic tf-idf as script score, like:

```
"similarity": {
      "scripted_tfidf": {
        "type": "scripted",
        "script": {
          "source": "double tf = Math.sqrt(doc.freq); double idf = Math.log((field.docCount+1.0)/(term.docFreq+1.0)) + 1.0; double norm = 1/Math.sqrt(doc.length); return query.boost * tf * idf * norm;"
        }
      }
    }
```

which in details says:

```
tf-idf = query.boost * tf * idf * norm
```

with:

```
tf = Math.sqrt(doc.freq)
idf = Math.log((field.docCount+1.0)/(term.docFreq+1.0)) + 1.0
norm = 1/Math.sqrt(doc.length)
```

So my approach to implement sklearn's tf-idf would be:

```
"double tf = doc.freq; double idf = Math.log((field.docCount+1.0)/(term.docFreq+1.0)) + 1.0; return tf * idf;"
```

But with this implementation i get horrible search results which are way worse than the ones of sklearn (while the default elasticsearch implementation of tf-idf outperforms sklearn).

So my question here is: What's the error in my scripted tf-idf implementation?

(I know that sklearn suggests to normalize tf-idf before calculating a similarity score with cosine similarity, but as elasticsearch is not doing this, i thought the resulting scores and thefore the query search results, should be the same.)